# R: pivoting & subtotals in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, pivot, subtotal

Pivoting and subtotals are common auxiliary steps in spreadsheets and SQL.

Assume a data.table with the fields `date, myCategory, revenue`. Assume that you want to know the proportion of day revenue of all revenue and the proportion of day revenue within different subgroup such that

```
 b[,{
    #First auxiliary variable of all revenue
    totalRev = sum(revenue)                     #SUBGROUP OF ALL REV

    #Second auxiliary variable of revenue by date, syntax wrong! How to do this?
    {totalRev_date=sum(revenue), by=list(date)} #DIFFERENT SUBGROUP, by DATE's rev

    #Within the subgroup by date and myCategory, we will use 1st&2nd auxiliary vars
    .SD[,.(Revenue_prop_of_TOT=revenue/totalRev,
          ,Revenue_prop_of_DAY=revenue/totalRev_date)    ,by=list(myCategory,date)]
    },]
```

where we need to compute the auxiliary sums, all revenue of specific day and all revenue of whole history.

The end result should look like this:

```
date            myCategory       Revenue_prop_of_TOT         Revenue_prop_of_DAY
2019-01-01      Cat1             0.002                       0.2
...
```

where you see that the auxiliary variables are only help functions.

### **How can you pivot and compute subtotals within R data.table?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using `data.table::cube`:

```
cb <- cube(DT, sum(value), by=c("date","category"), id=TRUE)

cb[grouping==0L, .(date, category,

    PropByDate = V1 / cb[grouping==1L][.SD, on="date", x.V1],

    PropByCategory = V1 / cb[grouping==2L][.SD, on="category", x.V1],

    PropByTotal = V1 / cb[grouping==3L, V1]
)]
```

output:

```
   date category PropByDate PropByCategory PropByTotal
1:    1        1  0.3333333      0.2500000         0.1
2:    1        2  0.6666667      0.3333333         0.2
3:    2        1  0.4285714      0.7500000         0.3
4:    2        2  0.5714286      0.6666667         0.4
```

data:

```
DT <- data.table(date=c(1, 1, 2, 2), category=c(1, 2, 1, 2), value=1:4)

#   date category value
#1:    1        1     1
#2:    1        2     2
#3:    2        1     3
#4:    2        2     4
```

Comment: what is the benefit of data.table::cube? This is the description `"Calculate aggregates at various levels of groupings producing multiple (sub-)totals. Reflects SQLs GROUPING SETS operations.`.

Comment: its actually coming from sql where a lot of aggregations are preprocessed to speed up subsequent analysis. i see that your problem is doing a lot of aggregation and cube came to mind

Comment: I didn't know about cube, more info [here](https://jozef.io/r912-datatable-grouping-sets/). It seems it's useful if you want to replicate the excel pivot tables, add subtotals, etc.

Comment: The cube is fantastic, also `groupingsets` is something to look at. If I recall correctly, cube can be implemented with `groupingsets`, hence a little more generic for pivoting in R. +1 for finding this awesome tool.

Comment: @hhh you recall correctly, take a look at `data.table:::cube.data.table`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm understanding correctly what you intend but please let me know in the comments if you need a different output.

```
b = data.table(date = rep(seq.Date(Sys.Date()-99, Sys.Date(), "days"), each=2), 
               myCategory = c("a", "b"), 
               revenue = rnorm(100, 200))


# global total, just create a constant
totalRev = b[, sum(revenue)]

# Total revenue at myCategory and date level / total Revenue
b[, Revenue_prop_of_TOT:=sum(revenue)/totalRev, by=.(myCategory, date)]

# you can calculate totalRev_date independently
b[, totalRev_date:=sum(revenue), by=date]

# If these are all the columns you have you don't need the sum(revenue) and by calls
b[, Revenue_prop_of_DAY:=sum(revenue)/totalRev_date, by=.(myCategory, date)]
```

Finally I would wrap it in a function.

```
revenue_total <- function(b){ 
  totalRev = b[, sum(revenue)]
  b[, Revenue_prop_of_TOT:=sum(revenue)/totalRev, by=.(myCategory, date)]
  b[, totalRev_date:=sum(revenue), by=date]
  b[, Revenue_prop_of_DAY:=sum(revenue)/totalRev_date, by=.(myCategory, date)]
  b
}

b = revenue_total(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Options for pivoting and subtotals in R*

1. cube answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57067410/164148)
2. groupingsets commented by marbel [here](https://jozef.io/r912-datatable-grouping-sets/)